# C# ClickOnce install folder - how windows generate the folder names

Tags: c#, windows, clickonce, directory

I would like to know how Windows `generate folder`, where will be `ClickOnce application` installed.

In Startmenu is "shortcut" to file, what is putted in some "startrek" folder like:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GT??4KXX.PRJ\EGV???1G.??C\prin..tion_7???5a2?????74b6_0000.0002_1dae????89111c35

What does those folder names mean?

---

For example:

If i will have for example some `settings.txt` file where i want that user can change some parameters of the application. Is there way how to know, WHERE it will be installed and WHERE the file is? (Where user will find this settings.txt file).

I know that i can create the file for example in C:\ and after start the application i will modify the file in "strong" path. But i dont really like too much files, folders, whatever in C:\ and i prefer to have settings files in same folder like the application. But with ClickOnce installations is it really hard - impossible - to find that file.

It seems like when the "startrek" is something like hash of the project.

---

So i would like to know what does the folder means and if its some hash of the project or what is that.

Comment: Maybe you should not use fully qualified paths in your setting file. Use relative file references to things within the applications folder

Comment: That problem was that i NEED the fully qualified paths..i need it just for information for some peoples what doesnt understand computers and i need to say them "HERE IS THIS FILE..OPEN IT AND MODIFY IT"..it wasnt problem that i need to work with the file in my app (there i use relative ref).. but i solve it with app settings, its not best solution but its atleast better than nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the folder that contains your executable, you can use the [Assembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) property.

For example:

```
string exeFolder = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

However, if you want to store settings for your ClickOnce app, you shouldn't do it by writing a file to the .exe's folder.

Instead, you should use [Microsoft's Application Settings support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms228995.aspx). Doing it any other way is going to be a lot of extra hassle, and Microsoft's support is very good. It does need half an hour to read through the documentation, but it's far and away the best thing to do, IMHO.

(I'm assuming that you only need the settings to be stored on the local PC for the same user to use later. If you want the settings to follow the user around (i.e. roaming settings), you can't use the Microsoft support.)

If you have more complex settings that you want to store in a file that you create directly, you should consider using the isolated storage that the answer from JRoughan mentions.

Comment: Ok i solve that with the settings of the app. Settings are same when application is updated so its the best i can do and that another user will access it.."i dont care" ;D (i have not another possibility) :] thnks

Comment: I think you can choose - on a setting by setting basis - whether to store that setting for all users or for the current user. There's a settings editor built-in, and you choose it in there somewhere I think.

Answer (score 4):

From inside the ClickOnce app you can find the default directory where files are stored using

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

Or you can use [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) and choose whether you want to save per application or per user.

I don't think it's possible to determine these folders from outside the app itself. If you need a known location you'll have to hard-code it.

**Update**

I also don't believe it's possible to infer what the install directory will be for an app. It would be unwise to use even if possible as updates to the app will not be in the same location.

Comment: thanks you very much, i will look at the isolated storage, it would be helpfull. The DataDirectory is not right way for me, because i need to set for example the settings.txt manualy (therefore the "ask":] )..Programmaticaly it is not complicated for me, but how i said, i need to set the file manualy so i need to know the path to the app.. Thanks you.. TO UPDATE: yes, if its updated, the folder is not same, thats second problem :D